# Flowchart Control for WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, flowchart

I need to design a control that can create/manipulate a really simple Algorithm flow chart. It will only have conditional (if, if,else) and assignment blocks.

Some key features that I need to implement are:

1. Users can freely add/manipulate/remove conditional and statement blocks on anywhere desired.
2. The chart can be folded/expanded. (For instance, if I clicked on the plus button right below b=3 assignment statement, everything below would be folded)

Are there any non-proprietary controls available for .NET that I can use? If not, what are some strategies that I should employ to tackle this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered hosting the [WorkflowDesigner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835242.aspx)?

Comment: Getting Started Tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489454(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Diagram Designer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4). You should be able to use it for inspiration/help to create a flow chart control that suit your needs.

Comment: Yes, this was the first thing that came up in my mind. I would've liked something that can automatically design an algorithm flow chart, not just draw a regular flowchart.

Answer (score 1):

Another non-free WPF tool for the job http://www.nwoods.com/

Comment: The question asked specifically for free tools, though.

Answer (score -1):

By non-proprietory do you mean free?  You may want to check out Add Flow
http://www.lassalle.com/

Its not free , but well worth it.